GR and Riemann Surfaces -- does the complex plane have anything to do with it?
I have only the vaguest understanding of Riemann Surfaces -- my sense is that Einstein used them in General Relativity because of their shape.
But Riemann Surfaces I think are not just deformations of a 2 dimensional plane but specifically of the complex plane. Does this property of Riemann Surfaces have anything to do with GR -- are complex numbers used in the describing how gravity works and is that why Einstein used Riemann Surfaces?

Where did you get the idea that Einstein ever used Riemann surfaces?

This question seems mainly spurred by a conflation of a Riemann surface (which is a 1-dimensional complex manifold), and a (pseudo)Riemannian manifold (which is the underlying geometry of GR).

so in fact GR does not rely on complex numbers?

$\uparrow$ Right.

maybe just close the question, then. i misunderstood. my experience with riemann was solely from a barely-understood complex analysis course.
